# How do I deploy and manage a small scale Java desktop application?

Tags: java, deployment, hosting, cloud-hosting

Some relevant background:
My application is a Java app compiled into a .exe via JSmooth. The anticipated user base would likely be a few hundred users, but could grow well beyond that, as it's a community specific application.

How it works:

2 .jar files, one that preforms initial checks, another with the meat of the application.

Ideally, the init jar displays the splash, checks the version in desktop.txt against server.txt, if they differ, it prompts the user to update.

What I need to figure out:

1) What is a cheap, scalable hosting service that I could use as the file host for updates?

2) How can I create an "updater" to actually preform the jar replacement?  My current solution is simply writing an updater in Java, but I was hoping for something like the installers people are more familiar with.

All of the research I've done has resulted in lackluster results, as 99% of hosting searches result in site hosting results. I just need an update repository with reasonable security. i.e., decent DDoS resistance and not left wide open to the Internet.

Edit: formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Easy to do and very foolish cheap with Amazon S3 or Joyent Manta as both support time-limited signed URLs and headers (which can contain a SHA-1 of the file) to check to see if the update is needed before downloading
2. On startup your app would check the update URL to see if it has changed.  If it has changed, download the JARs.  Do this before the app loads classes from those JARs.  Updating the updater itself will be trickier so consider that an update might need a new update URL to prevent expiry.

Comment: My pleasure.  Can you set my answer as the correct one? :)

Comment: Sadly I can't seem to do so on my phone :/ So I will when I'm home.